# Maximo de reputação diário

Tags: debate

O que acontece com a reputação ganhada quando seu limite diário (200 pontos) é atingido? Vejo que existe muitos membros com mais de 5000 pontos de reputação logo imagino que muitos deles devem receber uma quantidade grande de reputação diariamente.